# How to revert SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have set SQL_MODE using this SQL.
**SQL is** SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

Now we want to revert it.
Please suggest me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

First run this;

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%';
```

and

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%';
```

Then you'll get result like this:

[image]

Copy the `Value` and remove `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`. Please note some variables setting might be different between 'variables' and 'global variables' so make sure that and if there's a difference, copy both separately. Then run this command:

```
SET sql_mode='';
```

and

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

And to set back without the `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` variable, this:

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

and

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Please note that the above are only example. Make sure to get your original variable before you perform this. 
Once you've done, you should flush or restart your db.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below SQLs:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

------------------Your SQL--------------

```
SET SESSION sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

I hope this SQL will beneficial for you.